# Sets that are half-satisfied

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

Let $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and $A_1,\dots,A_k\subseteq S$. Assume that, among the sets $A_i$'s, $1$ appears as least as frequently as $2$, which appears as least as frequently as $3$, etc.

Let $B = \{2,4,6,\dots\}$. A set $A_i$ is *half-satisfied* if at least half of its members (rounded down) are in $B$. What is the largest constant $c$ such that at least a $c$-fraction of the $A_i$'s must be half-satisfied?

*Example:* $A_1=\{1,3\},A_2=\{2,4\},A_3=\{1,5\}$. Then only $A_2$ is half-satisfied, so $c\le 1/3$.

Intuitively, the numbers in $B$ appear together roughly as frequently as the numbers in $S\setminus B$, so the fraction of half-satisfied sets should not be too low. Is there a way to quantify this idea? A difficulty is that the sets $A_i$'s may have different cardinalities, which means that, in some ways, they are initially not equally important.

Comment: Just to clarify -- sets like $\{1\}$ and $\{1,2,3\}$ are half-satisfied, yes?

Comment: @CarlSchildkraut Yes (because of the "rounded down")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One family of sets satisfying this property is
$$\{1,3\},\{1,5\},\dots,\{1,2k-1\},\{2,4,\dots,2k\},$$
which gives an upper bound of
$$c\leq \frac1{\lceil n/2\rceil}.$$
For the lower bound, for a set $A_i$,

- let $b_i$ be the number of even elements of $A_i$ strictly less than $n$, and
- let $c_i$ be the number of odd elements of $A_i$ strictly greater than $1$.
  We have (i) if $b_i\geq c_i$, then $A_i$ is half-satisfied, (ii) $b_i\leq \lceil n/2\rceil-1$, and (iii) by double counting,
  $$\sum_i(b_i-c_i)\geq 0.$$
  Suppose there are $t$ negative summands and $u$ nonnegative summands in the above; then by (ii) and (iii)
  $$u\left(\left\lceil\frac n2\right\rceil-1\right)\geq \sum_{i:b_i\geq c_i}(b_i-c_i)\geq t.$$
  By (i), since $A_i$ is half-satisfied whenever $b_i\geq c_i$, this implies the proportion of half-satisfied sets is at least
  $$\frac{u}{t+u}\geq \frac{1}{1+(\lceil n/2\rceil-1)}=\frac1{\lceil n/2\rceil},$$
  as desired.